# How to find the difference between two images, even if the object in one of the images is slightly rotated

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Give two input images:
i) [Master.png (Master image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOecZ.png)

ii) [query2.png (Rotated object inside the Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60LdT.png)

After I align the images I am getting this:
[The image is a little blurred compared to the master image and there are black edges being formed as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZMHY.jpg)

The output after matching the aligned and master image is wrong.

How to find and highlight the difference between the aligned and the master image.

Comment: please add some code, read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: you seem to do "feature matching" and the result looks reasonable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The process of alignment is called **registration**. What you are calling master image is called **Fixed Image**. And your aligned image is called **Moving Image**.
There are two ways to evaluate registration visually: **Differencing** & **Checkerboard**. In the example below, I'll show the visual registration evaluation for translation example using ITK. Rotation is also similar. You can use similar concepts for OpenCV. You can ignore the registration part as you have already done it, but displaying here for completeness. You can straight goto "Difference between two images" below. Ideally you should post your own code - how you did registration, so that others can continue from there.

```
import itk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import square, closing
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
%matplotlib inline
```

Let us first see the raw images

```
path1 = '../data/3_T1.png'
path2 = '../data/3_T2.png'

PixelType = itk.US    # unsigned short
 
PixelType = itk.F 
Dimension = 2
FixedImageType  = itk.Image[PixelType, Dimension]
MovingImageType = itk.Image[PixelType, Dimension]

FixedImageReaderType  = itk.ImageFileReader[FixedImageType]
MovingImageReaderType = itk.ImageFileReader[MovingImageType]

fixedImageReader  = FixedImageReaderType.New()
movingImageReader = MovingImageReaderType.New()

fixedImageFile = path1
movingImageFile = path2

fixedImageReader.SetFileName(fixedImageFile)
movingImageReader.SetFileName(movingImageFile)
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax1.imshow(itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(fixedImageReader.GetOutput()), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_title('Fixed Image (T1)')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.imshow(itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(movingImageReader.GetOutput()), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
ax2.set_title('Moving Image (T2)')
ax2.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Registration Parameters and Settings

```
InternalPixelType = itk.F
InternalImageType = itk.Image[InternalPixelType, Dimension]

TransformType    = itk.TranslationTransform[itk.D, Dimension]
OptimizerType    = itk.GradientDescentOptimizer
InterpolatorType = itk.LinearInterpolateImageFunction[InternalImageType, itk.D]
RegistrationType = itk.ImageRegistrationMethod[InternalImageType, InternalImageType]  
MetricType       = itk.MutualInformationImageToImageMetric[InternalImageType, InternalImageType]

transform     = TransformType.New()
optimizer     = OptimizerType.New()
interpolator  = InterpolatorType.New()
registration  = RegistrationType.New()
metric        = MetricType.New()

registration.SetOptimizer(optimizer)
registration.SetTransform(transform)
registration.SetInterpolator(interpolator)
registration.SetMetric(metric)
```

Normalize the statistical distribution of the two input images to simplify the computation of the mutual information i.e. rescale the intensities of the input images in order to produce an output image with zero mean and unit variance

```
FixedNormalizeFilterType  = itk.NormalizeImageFilter[FixedImageType,  InternalImageType]
MovingNormalizeFilterType = itk.NormalizeImageFilter[MovingImageType, InternalImageType]

fixedNormalizer  = FixedNormalizeFilterType.New()
movingNormalizer = MovingNormalizeFilterType.New()
```

Additionally, low-pass filtering of the images to be registered will also increase robustness against noise.

```
GaussianFilterType = itk.DiscreteGaussianImageFilter[ InternalImageType, InternalImageType]
fixedSmoother  = GaussianFilterType.New()
movingSmoother = GaussianFilterType.New()

fixedSmoother.SetVariance( 2.0 )
movingSmoother.SetVariance( 2.0 )

# standard deviation of the Gaussian kernel
metric.SetFixedImageStandardDeviation(0.4)
metric.SetMovingImageStandardDeviation(0.4)

fixedNormalizer.SetInput(  fixedImageReader.GetOutput() )
movingNormalizer.SetInput( movingImageReader.GetOutput() )

fixedSmoother.SetInput( fixedNormalizer.GetOutput() )
movingSmoother.SetInput( movingNormalizer.GetOutput() )
```

Set the Input Images for registration

```
registration.SetFixedImage(    fixedSmoother.GetOutput()    )
registration.SetMovingImage(   movingSmoother.GetOutput()   )
fixedNormalizer.Update()
fixedImageRegion = fixedNormalizer.GetOutput().GetBufferedRegion()
registration.SetFixedImageRegion( fixedImageRegion )
```

Initialize

```
initialParameters = transform.GetParameters()
initialParameters[0] = 0.0 # Initial offset in mm along X
initialParameters[0] = 0.0 # Initial offset in mm along Y

registration.SetInitialTransformParameters( initialParameters )
```

We should now define the number of spatial samples to be considered in the metric computation. We have postponed this setting until we had done the preprocessing of the images because the number of samples is usually defined as a fraction of the total number of pixels in the fixed image.

The number of spatial samples can usually be as low as $1%$ of the total number of pixels in the fixed image. Increasing the number of samples improves the smoothness of the metric from one iteration to another and therefore helps when this metric is used in conjunction with optimizers that rely of the continuity of the metric values. The trade-off, of course, is that a larger number of samples result in longer computation times per every evaluation of the metric.

```
numberOfPixels = fixedImageRegion.GetNumberOfPixels()
numberOfSamples = numberOfPixels * 0.01
numberOfSamples = int(numberOfSamples)
metric.SetNumberOfSpatialSamples( numberOfSamples )
metric.ReinitializeSeed( 121212 ) # For consistent results when regression testing
```

Optimizer Settings - Since larger values of mutual information indicate better matches than smaller values, we need to maximize the cost function

```
optimizer.SetNumberOfIterations( 200 )
optimizer.MaximizeOn()
optimizer.SetLearningRate( 15.0 )
```

Execute the registration

```
registration.Update()
```

Extract Results

```
finalParameters = registration.GetLastTransformParameters()
TranslationAlongX = finalParameters[0]
TranslationAlongY = finalParameters[1]
numberOfIterations = optimizer.GetCurrentIteration()
bestValue = optimizer.GetValue()

print("Result = ")
print(" Translation X = " + str(TranslationAlongX))
print(" Translation Y = " + str(TranslationAlongY))
print(" Iterations    = " + str(numberOfIterations))
print(" Metric value  = " + str(bestValue))
print(" Numb. Samples = " + str(numberOfSamples))
```

Output:

```
Result = 
 Translation X = 10.029903702181082
 Translation Y = 9.982473996881163
 Iterations    = 200
 Metric value  = 0.5775022237597298
 Numb. Samples = 530
```

Transform:

```
finalTransform = TransformType.New()
finalTransform.SetParameters( finalParameters )
finalTransform.SetFixedParameters( transform.GetFixedParameters() )
```

Resample

```
ResampleFilterType = itk.ResampleImageFilter[MovingImageType, FixedImageType]
resample = ResampleFilterType.New()
resample.SetTransform( finalTransform )
resample.SetInput( movingImageReader.GetOutput() )

fixedImage = fixedImageReader.GetOutput()

resample.SetSize(    fixedImage.GetLargestPossibleRegion().GetSize() )
resample.SetOutputOrigin(  fixedImage.GetOrigin() )
resample.SetOutputSpacing( fixedImage.GetSpacing() )
resample.SetOutputDirection( fixedImage.GetDirection() )
resample.SetDefaultPixelValue( 100 )

OutputPixelType = itk.ctype('unsigned char')
OutputImageType = itk.Image[OutputPixelType, Dimension]

resample.Update()
```

**Difference between two images**

```
difference = itk.SubtractImageFilter.New(Input1=fixedImage, Input2=resample)
resample.SetDefaultPixelValue(1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 12))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax1.imshow(itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(resample), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_title('Registered Image')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax3.imshow(itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(difference), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
ax3.set_title('Difference After Registration')
ax3.axis('off')

identityTransform = TransformType.New()
identityTransform.SetIdentity()
resample.SetTransform(identityTransform)
difference.Update()

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
ax4.imshow(itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(difference), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
ax4.set_title('Difference Before Registration')
ax4.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Fixed/moving image checkerboard**

```
CheckerBoardFilterType = itk.CheckerBoardImageFilter[FixedImageType]
checker = CheckerBoardFilterType.New()
checker.SetInput1( fixedImage )
checker.SetInput2( resample.GetOutput() )

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax1.imshow(itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(checker), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_title('Before Registration')

resample.SetTransform( finalTransform )
checker.SetInput2( resample.GetOutput() )

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.imshow(itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(checker), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
ax2.set_title('After Registration')
ax2.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]